# InvalidSelectorException when using selenium webdriver with intellij

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, browser-automation

Just started learning Selenium. So the inspect element of the website is as follows:

```
<select ng-model="selectedFacility" ng-options="facility as facility.name for facility in facilities" ng-change="afterSelectingFacility()" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"> <option> </option> </select>
```

I am using the following code to access the element:

```
Select facility = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class=('ng - pristine ng - valid ng-touched']")));
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector input[class=('ng - pristine ng - valid ng-touched'] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred: InvalidSelectorError: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

I have gone through some posts in stackoverflow but they didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

When selecting by class using Css, why not use the correct syntax?

```
By.cssSelector("select.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-touched")
```

You could also use xpath:

```
By.xpath("//select[@ng-model='selectedFacility' and @class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched']");
```

Answer (score -1):

Your Selector should be

```
By.cssSelector("select[class='ng - pristine ng - valid ng-touched']")



Select facility =new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[class='ng - pristine ng - valid ng-touched']")));
```

EDIT-I

Try with this

```
By.cssSelector("select[ng-model='selectedFacility']")
```

Comment: Why are you including ( (bracket symbol) at class value starting ? remove that and try.==> "input[class='ng - pristine ng - valid ng-touched']"

Comment: *** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=input[class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched']}

Comment: In your question itself you posted it and we can operate methods Select class only on select tag but not input tag.